# Sendmail - relay to Office 365 [Smart host with non default port]

Tags: linux, sendmail, office365

I need to relay email in sendmail as follows

- Host example.mail.protection.outlook.com
- Port 2525
- No authentication
- No SSL

I know I need to set the following in the sendmail.mc file:
`` define(`SMART_HOST', `example.mail.protection.outlook.com')dnl ``

If I needed to change ports, do I just do the following:
`` define(`SMART_HOST', `example.mail.protection.outlook.com:2525')dnl ``

I assume if I don't specify a username/password then there is no authentication.

How do I ensure that TLS is disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may make `relay` mailer connect to port other than default 25.
Sendmail by default uses `relay` mailer unless another mailer is explicitely specified (`mailer:host.domain`).

```
# sendmail.mc
define(`SMART_HOST',`relay.example.com`)dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 2525')dnl
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132711/using-port-587-with-sendmail